# How access data from sp

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly. I want to do a subroutine and I need to follow the convention. The caller put the value in register then you push to the stack. In subroutine you need to extract from the stack but I have some problem. Here is my code:

```
.286
.model huge
.stack 100h

mov bl, 'd' ; just put d to test
push bx
call putch
call terminate

; ---------- void putch(char c) ----------

putch:
; Print character into screen
; bl <- character to be printed

mov bx, [sp+4] ; THIS IS THE ERROR.

mov dl, bl  ; store the argument into dl
mov ah, 2h  ; print the character
int 21h

ret 4       ; return

; ---------- end of function ----------
terminate:
mov ah, 4ch     ; terminate the program
int 21h
END start
```

My prof said you use `mov bx, [sp+offset]` to get the value from stack but it doesn't compile. I use 286 assembly. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: You have the comment, *; THIS IS THE ERROR.* but what is the error? Please indicate what error you saw. And what assembler (`nasm`?...)

Comment: tasm, The error is Illegal indexing mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not exist `mov bx, [sp+offset]` on 286 assembly.

You can use

```
mov bp,sp
mov bx,[bp+offset]
```

Comment: Did you notice the offset must be 2 in stead of 4? *call putch* only uses 2 bytes on the stack in 16 bit code. Same applies to *ret 2*!

Comment: Yes I noticed that error. Thank you for letting me know :)